# Qt: Delete parent widget while retaining the child?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qobject

I have a Qt parent widget that displays a child widget.

I need to delete the parent widget.

I might (or not) later attach the child to a different parent and display it inside the new container.

I do not have access to the second parent at the time I delete the first parent.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried calling `QWidget::setParent(nullptr)` on the child widget? You should either create a getter for this widget or pass the widget itself to the constructor, so you already have it outside the object's scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First hide the child widget using `hide()` or `setVisible(false)` methods of *QWidget*. Then make the child widget have no parent using `setParent(nullptr)`, which makes it a top level window, which is why you needed to hide it first.

To later re-use the widget, add it to appropriate new layout, which also sets it parent. You need to call its `show()` or `setVisible(true)` method for it too, or it will stay hidden.